# How do I use a VBscript to determine if the monitor(s) connected to a machine is an LCD or CRT?

Tags: vbscript, wmi, monitor, crt, lcd

I am trying to add info to a VBscript that will determine if the monitor(s) connected to the current machine is an LCD or CRT.  I know I can get the EDID info from HKLM\System\CCS\Enum\DISPLAY but I can't use that to determine the monitor type.  And the only consistent info I can grab from the WMI classes Win32_DesktopMonitor, Win32_DisplayConfiguration, and Win32_VideoController are the screen resolution and refresh rate.  There are some screen resolutions that are usually only used by LCDs (like widescreen ones), but that is not reliable.

Without having to build a table of model names, what can I do to determine if the monitor is an LCD or CRT?

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Vista you can dig way down into this function - [GetMonitorTechnologyType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd692947%28VS.85%29.aspx).
I'm guessing this should be available to VBScript via COM.